# Are mutations through an unmodified atomic reference visible?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java.util.concurrent, java-memory-model

Let's say I have an atomic reference to a mutable class type `Foo`:

```
AtomicReference<Foo> foo = new AtomicReference<Foo>(new Foo());
```

Thread A writes to the `Foo` object:

```
foo.get().write(42);
```

And thread B reads from the `Foo` object:

```
int x = foo.get().read();
```

Note that the atomic reference itself is never modified! That is, I do not call `foo.set` in my code.

Is thread B guaranteed to observe the value that was last written by thread A?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is thread B guaranteed to observe the value that was last written by
>   thread A?

No.  It would be equivalent to:

```
volatile Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.write(42);
```

All writes that happen prior to the initial assignment of foo will be visible after foo is non-null.  After that however there is no guarantee on when a thread will see the write of `foo.write(42)` to occur.

Answer (score 1):

No.

You cannot simply make X thread safe by making access to a specific instance of it atomic.

In order for this to be thread safe, you would have to make the underlying class itself thread safe, not just access to it.